# Tumblr: Show page links in a menu?

Tags: themes, blogs, tumblr

I have created a custom Tumblr theme and have a number of pages on my blog. I want to create a navigation menu near the top of my template but am unsure of how to do this.

I have added the lines:

```
        {block:HasPages} {/block:HasPages}
        {block:Pages} {/block:Pages}
```

But this has no effect.

Does anyone know the correct way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do

```
{block:HasPages}
  {block:Pages}
    <a href="{URL}">{Label}</a>
  {/block:Pages}
{/block:HasPages}
```